# Using ATL ActiveX control inside WPF Window application

Tags: wpf

The COM object was not created. The following is XAML code:

    Title="Window1" Height="373" Width="701" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    
        
            
            
        
            
                
            
            Draw Contour

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="c:/cs3/TextActiveX/TestActiveX/Image.bmp"/>-->
    <Image x:Key="MyImageSource" Source="C:\CS3\TestActiveX\TestActiveX\Image.bmp"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

On load event I check:
 if (!this.imageView.Created)
and it appears that control was not created (this.ocx is null).
I understand that something wrong with registration. I tried re-register - does not work. I tried run as admin and even disable UAC and restart Vista - does not work. But if I run MFC test application or HTML script it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry text was too long and it was cut. I am using WindowsFormHost to host ATL based ActiveX control. I defined both inside XAML code.